Show that $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x>0, 0<y<x^2\}$ is not a star domain

Show that $M:=\{(x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x>0, 0<y<x^2\}$ is not a star domain.

If I draw a picture, then it's easy to verify that due to the slope of $x^2$ we can always find a point $(a,b)\in M$ that is part of the line between a possible star point $(z_1,z_2)$ and $(a,b)$. But I am struggling to express it in a formal way.
A simple example supports this idea. Let be $(2,1)$ the possible star point then we choose $(100, 9999)$ and define the straight line by $L:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by $L(t):={1\choose 2}+t{100-1\choose 9999-1}={1+99t\choose 2+9998t}.$ Next we see that the point $L\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)={50.5\choose 5001}\notin M$.

How do I formalize this idea?
My approach
Let be $(z_1,z_2)\in M$ a possible star point and $(a,b)\in M$ another point we are trying to construct accordingly. Then $L:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ with
$$
L(t):={z_1 \choose z_2}+t{a-z_1\choose b-z_2}={z_1+t(a-z_1)\choose z_2+t(b-z_2)}.
$$
We set $t:=\frac{1}{2}$ and try to find a $n$ such that $\left(z_1+\frac{1}{2}(a-z_1)\right)^2<z_2+\frac{1}{2}(b-z_2)$. Now we try to tinker around with the point $(a,b)$, for example we set $a=\sqrt{nz_1+1}$, $b=nz_1$ and plug it into the inequality. However it makes it only more complicated. Maybe there is a more clever approach or a better choice of $(a,b)$?
any suggestions are welcome

We may restrict our search to $b=a^2$ and $a>z_1$. Although $(a,b)$ not in $M$, we may take $b'<b$ as close as we like to $b$ and have $(a,b')$ in $M$.
Now the equation of the line passing through $(z_1,z_2)$ and $(a,b)$ is:
$$
y=(a^2-z_2)\left(\frac{x-z_1}{a-z_1}\right)+z_2.
$$
The intersection points with the curve $y=x^2$ are then given by equating:
$$
x^2=(a^2-z_2)\left(\frac{x-z_1}{a-z_1}\right)+z_2.
$$
Note we know $x=a$ is one solution. We must determine the other, to see if the interval $(z_1,z_2)-(a,b)$ ever crosses the curve.  That is, to show that $M$ is a star domain, we must show that for some choice of $a>z_1$, the other solution for $x$, is less than $a$.
By long division, we get $$
x^2- (a^2-z_2)\left(\frac{x-z_1}{a-z_1}\right)-z_2 = (x-a)\left(x-\frac{az_1-z_2}{a-z_1}\right)
$$
Thus we seek $a>z_1$ such that $$a-\left(\frac{az_1-z_2}{a-z_1}\right)>0,$$ as this corresponds to the interval $(z_1,z_2)-(a,b)$ crossing the curve $y=x^2$.
As we are looking in $a>z_1$, this is the same as $$a^2-2az_1+z_2>0.$$
Solving the quadratic, we see that we just need to take $a>z_1+\sqrt{z_1^2-z_2}$.
Alternatively, we could take $a<z_1-\sqrt{z_1^2-z_2}$, in which case the other solution for $x$ is greater than $a$, so the crossing point is still in the interval $(a,b)- (z_1,z_2)$.
Finally pick $b'<b$ sufficiently close to $b$, so that the interval $(a,b')- (z_1,z_2)$ still passes out of $M$ before returning.

Observe the point $T(2\epsilon, \epsilon^2)$. Clearly, as $ 0 < \epsilon^2 < (2\epsilon)^2$, this point is in the set. The center must "see" this point. If we calulate the tangent to $y=x^2$ going through point $T$ we get the line $y = \underbrace{\left(2\sqrt{3}+4 \right)\epsilon}_{k_0}\cdot x - \left(4\sqrt{3}+7\right) \epsilon^2$, which touches the curve at $x_0=\frac{\epsilon}{2-\sqrt{3}}$.
The possible center of the region is a point $C(x,y)$ with either $C_x < x_0$ or on a line going through $T$, which contains points with $x > x_0$. In the second case due to $y=x^2$ being convex the line must be below the tangent, so $k < k_0$, for it to be contained. For negative $k$ the intersection of this line with the $x$-axis is $0=k(x-2\epsilon)+\epsilon^2$, so $-k(x-2\epsilon) = \epsilon^2$ and because $x>x_0$ then $-k(x_0-2\epsilon) \leq \epsilon^2$, so $k \geq \frac{\epsilon^2}{2\epsilon-x_0}$.
To conclude, when $\epsilon \to 0$:

In the first case: $\left(C_x < x_0 = \frac{\epsilon}{2-\sqrt{3}}\right),$ so $C_x$ must be $0$ which is a contradiction.
In the second case $\left(\frac{\epsilon^2}{2\epsilon-x_0} \leq k \leq \left(2\sqrt{3}+4 \right)\epsilon\right),$ we find that $k$ must be $0$, but this implies that $C_y = \epsilon^2$, which goes to $0$, another contradiction.


This is a link to a visualization: desmos

Another approach is to come at it from an intuitive point of view consider this picture that I came up with in my mind, and then realized in desmos:

It should be clear that this point can never be reached using a straight line from the point $p$, and most likely be formally proven true once we know what the black point is defined as.
I will show you how to construct the black point, and how to prove that the line connecting it the green point escapes outside of the graph.
Given a point $p = (p_1, p_2)$, we will find the point $s$ such that the tangent line at that location passes through $p$, to do so we recall that the tangent line is given by $t(s) = f ^ \prime (s) (x -s)  + f(s)$, in our case that is $t(s) = 2s (x - s) + s^2$, now we plug in our point to get
$$ p_y = 2s ( p_x - s) + s^2 = 2sp_x - 2s^2 + s^2 \iff -s^2 + s (2p_x) - p_y = 0 $$
We then use the quadratic equation to obtain the positive solution as we are restricting to positive x values, call this solution $\bar s$, then the black point $q$ is defined as $(\frac{\bar s}{2}, (\frac{\bar s}{2})^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2})$, this is simply getting a point to the left of the solution and forcing it inside the required region.
Now in order to show that the line connecting $p$ and $q$ must escape the shaded area we use the following property. Given a line segment $l_1$ from $(a_x, a_y)$ to $(b_x, b_y)$, and any $\epsilon > 0$ the line segment $l_2$ from $(a_x, a_y + \epsilon)$ to $(b_x, b_y)$, then for for all $x \in [a_x, b_x)$ we have that $l_1(x) < l_2(x)$.
Now in our case our black line forms a line segment from $(\frac{\bar s}{2}, 0)$ to $p$, and we know that $q$ has a vertical offset from the former point, therefore if we look at $l_1$ and $l_2$ (within this context) it must be that $l_1(\bar s) = f(\bar s) < l_2(\bar s)$ and therefore the point $(\bar s, l_2(\bar s))$ is not in the shaded area.
You can play with the desmos simulation here
